# Html and javascript: how to switch download link to button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a export to excel link on my page like:

```
<a download="queryResults.csv" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'datatable');">Export to CSV</a>
```

I would like to present it as a button, I tried something like:

```
<button download="queryResults.csv" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'datatable');">Export to CSV</button>
```

Hoe should I get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: Your markup must be working. http://jsfiddle.net/2nungu6x/ The problem must be in the ExcellentExport.csv function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <a download="queryResults.csv"  
   onclick="return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'datatable');" href="#"> 
   <button>Export to CSV</button>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button element has no `href` attribute. Instead you have to provide a `type` attribute, which has to be `type="button"`. See the specs here: [HTML button tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: It does not matter. All browsers will ignore unrecognized attributes.